# client communication error on Virtual Machine running on cloudstack

Tags: apache-cloudstack

I want to use terminal/console of ubuntu 14 installed on virtual machine running on cloudstack 4.6. I am able to use ubuntu 14 desktop normally but whenever I try to use the terminal from it, i get "Client communication error please retry later". Following is the screen shot of the error.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8rbN.png)

I am using college network behind a proxy server, could that be a problem ?
any suggestions ? Does anybody know where I am going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way to troubleshoot this - on the browser window that houses the broken terminal, do a view source. In there you'll find a URL direct to your console proxy server. Copy and paste that URL into a new window and see if you can hit it directly.  I'm guessing a firewall issue...